# How to know when SQLite query is finished

Tags: android, database, sqlite, retrofit

Ok, I've got this Retrofit Call that receives a list of objects and insert the into a local SQLite database. I want to display a message saying that the operation was successful with a Ok button that when pressed opens a new activity.

How do I check if my Query has finished so I can show the message?

```
final ContactApi contactApi = retrofit.create(ContactApi.class);

Call<List<Contact>> callContact = contactApi.getContact(token);
callContact.enqueue(new Callback<List<Contact>>() {
    @Override
     public void onResponse(Response<List<Contact>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

        List<Contact> contactList = response.body();

        if (contactList != null) {

            try {

                DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(TokenActivity.this, token);
                SQLiteDatabase conn = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                RepoContact repocontact = new RepoContact(conn);

                // Inserts each contact into the database
                    for (Contatc c : contactList) {

                        repositorioCadastro.inserirCadastro(c);

                        Log.i("ACTTOKEN", "Contact insert ID: " + c.getId());

                    }

            } catch (SQLiteException e) {
             Log.i("ACTTOKEN", "Faillure on insert: " + e.getMessage());
            }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

wrap your code in `try{...}finally{...}` blocks with a listener ( [`beginTransactionWithListener(SQLiteTransactionListener transactionListener)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransactionWithListener%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteTransactionListener%29)), and use the `transactionListner` to check whether everything went well within the transaction, in addition to everything within the try/finally.

what you have is good, just try adding `finally` block..
something like this..

```
 db.beginTransaction();
try {
 ...
 db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
 db.endTransaction();
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I've added the try{...}finally{...} blocks and the listener, now to test I have to do the code to show the message on the onCommit() or onRollback() method of the SQLiteTransactionListener?

Comment: Yes. If operation successful, it will go to finally() and then you can show the message.

Comment: Thanks, it works! But I'm wondering how can I do this with multiple queries? I have another screen which makes 5 retrofit calls and inserts into 5 different tables, so if I define a variable on each finally and then check them on the onCommit() method, the test will happen after every query is finished, right?

Comment: well, i don't know your code, so i can't say, but you can put run 5 queries in try block and perform your action in finally() block.

Comment: @Rafael What should "after every query is finished" mean? The purpose of a transaction is to finish all queries if you end it successfully. If you want to execute them independently you have to do it in different transactions.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a different loop, something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < contactList.size(); i++) {

    Contact c = contactList.get(i);
    repositorioCadastro.inserirCadastro(c);
    Log.i("ACTTOKEN", "Contact insert ID: " + c.getId());

    if(i == (contactList.size() - 1)) {
        // DO SOMETHING HERE
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may check insert statement return a long when query successfully executed then long value.

```
db.insert()
```

returns the row ID of the newly inserted row, or -1 if an error occurred